# Java Swing - draw consecutive rectangles after clicking a button

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw a rectangle after pressing a button. When I press for the first time the button it draws a rectangle. I'm trying to draw more rectangles adjacent to the first one after pressing the button again, but nothing is drawn. Can anybody help me?

This is the code that I use. Thank you very much

`class Coord{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
}
public class DrawRectangle extends JPanel {
    int x, y, width, height;

    public DrawRectangle (int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(this.width, this.height);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Coord coord = new Coord(); 

        final JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(null);
        center.setLocation(10, 10);
        center.setSize(300, 300);
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBounds(350,200,75,50); 
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                DrawRectangle component = new DrawRectangle(coord.x, coord.y, 30, 30);
                component.setLocation(coord.x, coord.y);
                component.setSize(component.getPreferredSize());
                center.add(component);
                center.repaint();
                coord.x += 30;
                coord.y +=30;
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(center);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your paintComponent() only ever draws a single rectangle. It clears the background of the panel and then draws the rectangle.

If you want multiple rectangles then you need to either:

1. Keep a List of Rectangle to draw and then iterate through the List each time and draw the rectangle
2. Draw each rectangle onto a BufferedImage and then just paint the BufferedImage.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both of these approaches. Try both to see which you prefer better.